# In Blazor WASM, how can I create a service that doesn't use authentication?

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-identity, blazor-webassembly

I created an ASP.NET hosted project with "Individual Accounts" for security. The ".Client" app comes with the below in the Program.cs class.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BlazorApp1.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

// Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>)
    .CreateClient("BlazorApp1.ServerAPI"));
```

I understand the first line creates an HttpClient service which adds a token to every request. The second line adds this HTTP client to any other service that requests "HttpClient".

If I add a service to the Program class:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPostService, PostService>();
```

which looks like this:

```
public class SomeService: ISomeService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public UserActivityService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
      _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<SomeOutputClass> Get()
    {
      return await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<SomeOutputClass>($"{apiUrl}");
    }
}
```

then the service will use the "BlazorApp1.ServerAPI" HttpClient always, which requires authentication.

What I want to do is be able to have a separate service that doesn't use this "BlazorApp1.ServerAPI" HttpClient, but uses an HttpClient which doesn't require authorization. Is there a way to do this? Maybe by creating a separate, named HttpClient and passing to the service like:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPostService, PostService>(OtherHttpClient);
```

Comment: Can't you just do this :
`builder.Services.AddScoped<IPostService, PostService>(sp => new PostService(new HttpClient(){ //Customize httpclient config }));` ? or define a `static` one and pass it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't know how to "customize httpclient config" or create a static one and pass it. Hence I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register multiple http clients with different configurations according to each service like this:

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IPostService, PostService>(client =>
{
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://apiUrl");
});
```

Then your service would be like this:

```
public class PostService : IPostService
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public PostService (HttpClient httpClient)
    {
      this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public Task<SomeType> Get()
    {
      return await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<SomeOutputClass>($"{apiUrl}");
    }
}
```

More info from Microsoft [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-ihttpclientfactory)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.